# Confusion with Postgis Topology and Geometrytype

Tags: topology, postgis-2.2

in the moment I try to understand the principles of postgis topology. While testing I discovered a behavior, which I don't understand.
I have a table public.test with a standard geometrycolumn type LINESTRING.
Then first I added a topology with:

select topology.CreateTopology(’testtopo’, 25832);

Next I added a column for the topologygeometry to the table test:

select topology.AddTopoGeometryColumn('testtopo','public','test','topogeom','LINESTRING');

At least I made an update to fill the column topogeom:

update test
set
topogeom = topology.toTopoGeom(geom, 'testtopo', 1, 2.0);

Till this point everything works fine. What I now doesn't understand is, that if I test the geometrytype with

select ST_GeometryType(topogeom) from test;

the result is a MULTILINESTRING.
When I query the relatet topology table with

select ST_GeometryType(geom) from testtopo.edge_data;

it is a LINESTRING.
Maybe someone has an explanation for that or is it possible to force the topology to be a LINESTRING?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think about postgis topology as a "container" and you can't "force" it to be a LINESTRING.
You choose the geometry type of topo-geometries at "topology level" as you you did with `AddTopoGeometryColumn`. (the 'test' column created is LINESTRING)

At the "physical level" of the topology, `node` table geometries are always points and `edge_data` table geometries are always linestring. There are base components of a topology.